# What is the correct syntax to integrate browser update script in a .js file?

Tags: javascript

Instead of copy/pasting the code below from [browser update](http://www.browser-update.org/#install) on every page, I'd like to include it in a scripts.js file.

My question is: do I need to wrap the code into something, for instance `$(function() {` since I will remove the `<script>` tags?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {}; 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js"); 
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: No need to wrap the code, just paste that code(without the script tags) into a js file and then include it.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out in the browser console? Why do you call your variable `$buoop`? The $-prefix is commonly used for variables denoting jQuery objects, is this true in this case as well?

Comment: @nietonfir it's not his code, he didn't name the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is horrible :-/ It simply dynamically loads the http://browser-update.org/update.js script in a `window.onload` handler.

If you want to load it as an external script, you can just directly load it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//browser-update.org/update.js" async></script>
```

> Do I need to wrap the code into something, for instance `$(function() {`, since I will remove the `<script>` tags?

No, you don't. However, if you have jQuery available, then you might simply use

```
$(function() {
     $.getScript("//browser-update.org/update.js");
});
```

Comment: This downloads the javascript immediately. I think, the idea behind his code that the javascript is loaded and executed asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, but the OP seems to not want that?

Comment: The OP wants to write the code **only once**. The solution is given by [APAD1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2827407/apad1). As regards the quality of the code itself, it uses [one of the methods Google does for tracking](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-track-google-analytics/).

Comment: @KitKat: What do you mean by "only once"? What solution has APAD1 given where? And I don't get your code quality argument, neither is horrible `onload` thing anywhere on that page you linked nor does this seem to be an official GA blog.

Comment: By "only once", I mean writing the code in an external file (once). When you need it, you link this file (not the whole block) in your HTML page. By "solution", I was referring to [the first comment of this page question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497889/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-integrate-browser-update-script-in-a-js-file/24498007?noredirect=1#comment37924432_24497889).
And by "quality", I was referring to the target script being asynchronous retrieved. Check the [source HTML code of StackOverflow home page](http://stackoverflow.com/) (the very last script tag).

Comment: @KitKat: Ah, thanks, you might rather have linked his comment than his userpage :-) Notice that both versions in my answer retrieve the script asynchronously as well, what I meant by "horrible" is that `window.onload` munging (which is definitely not done on SO)

Comment: Sure, overriding `onload` can be a little risky, especially if using this code [twice...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion)